# How to say "a very adult answer for a very adult question"?

Tags: translation

I watched Vladimir Putin do Q&A with high school students. One asked him

> What event most impacted your life?

Putin gave a very genuine answer related to the collapse of the Soviet Union that went way over the head of the 16-yr old. He then apologized and said:

> Forgive me. A very adult answer for a very adult question.

Is it correct to say:
大人**的**な質問 or 大人**みたい**な質問

and would the whole translation be

大人的な質問によって、大人的な答え、すみません。

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My personal recommendation would be to use the slightly colloquial 「オトナ**な**」 with 「オトナ」 in katakana.

I am sure that is not a word taught in Japanese-as-a-foreign-language, but I feel it would fit the situation well.

「大人的{おとなてき}な」 sounds way too stiff and 「大人みたいな」 sounds unnatural for using 「みたい」 because President Putin actually ***is*** an adult.

> 「ゴメンね。非常{ひじょう}にオトナな質問{しつもん}に対{たい}する非常にオトナな回答{かいとう}だったようだ。」